# Can I increase the number of frames in an rigid body simulation?

Tags: animation, keyframes, rigid-body-simulation

Every time I am making a simulation it is stopping at 250. Why? I want to make it longer..like 400 or something. Can I even do that? I tried increasing the frames at the menu bar where object mode at all those are written...I don't know what it is called since I am a noob. I even changed frame rate and frame range. It didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the number of frames in the Rigid Body Cache.

[image: Cache]